# Is there any option to block messages of a specific person without blocking him from calling?

Tags: android

Is there any option to block messages of a specific person without blocking him from calling in android phones.? also, will sender be able to know that he is blocked on calling/messaging to the phone in which he is being blocked?

Answer (score 0):

try this one...[SMS Blacklist for Android to block spam](http://code.google.com/p/sms-blacklist/)